# Decimals where they shouldn't be

Tags: vb.net

I nabbed a bit of code that prevents the user from entering non-numbers into a textbox, and monkeyed with it for a bit, trying to get it to include an exception for a decimal point. It didn't work, so I figured I'd just put the code back the way it was when I found it, because I don't yet know how to fix things if I break them.

Weird thing is, as soon as i put the code back to normal it suddenly started *doing the thing I originally wanted it to*, namely allowing the user to type a decimal into the textbox. This would be righteously excellent, if I could understand why in the name of Shiva my tiny program is doing something that it isn't programmed to do.

Have I somehow given birth to true AI and started the singularity?

EDIT (for clarity):

- I am a total beginner.
- I found this code that only allows numbers,
  backspace, and delete to be added to a textbox.
- I altered it, making assumptions about what it was doing, so that it would also allow a decimal point.
- This didn't work.
- I returned the code to how I found it.
- Only after this point did it start allowing the decimal point.
- This doesn't make sense, because it is now doing something that isn't in the code.
- Does the same thing happen to you when you put the code into Visual Studio?
- If so, why might this be happening?
- Is the world going to end because my computer is interpreting my desires and performing them in spite of all of the rules of space, time, and logic?

  ```
  Public Class Form1
      Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress

          If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Delete) Then

              e.Handled = True
              MessageBox.Show("numbers only", "baleted")

          End If

      End Sub
  End Class
  ```

Comment: This question is very unclear, can you try to just state exactly what the problem is and which part of the code you are confused about? If you can't reproduce the problem then the question is off-topic.

Comment: You should better take a deep look at the help pages (and to some questions/answers) to understand the expected format here. PS: out of all the weird parts in your text (-> better avoid this in the future), my favourite one is "monkeyed" (?!)

Comment: A decimal point is not a number.  Not the backspace or delete key either.  So it is entirely normal that your code rejects it.  There isn't much point in doing this, once you fix it then you still don't reject invalid input like 1.2.3.4.  And prevent, oh, two billion people that use a comma instead of a period from using your program.  Use the Validating event instead, call Decimal.TryParse().

Comment: @varocarbas To monkey with something = to play with it, having no idea how it works (and quite likely breaking it). It is used in a context of playful creativity and implies a nonchalant attitude to whatever is being done at the time.

Comment: @Hans Passant I was just trying to see if it would work. I don't have any goal with this other than to figure out the syntax to the point where I can deliberately change things and get the outcome I expect.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed definition. Never heard that expression before.

Answer (score 0):

I miss-understood your question.  I did a little rework on it. My bad!

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar = "." OrElse e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) OrElse IsNumeric(e.KeyChar)) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Not the prettiest thing I've ever barfed out, but basically this will check if the key pressed is a Decimal or a back space and allow those, I showed two different ways you can compare `e.KeyChar` in my code. If it isn't either on of those keys it will check if its a number using `IsNumeric`. If it's none of those things it will ignore it.  Not my best work, but you can build upon this, make it your own, make prettier.

e.Keychar is information that is gathered when the keypress event happens.  You can use the e.KeyChar to compare any button pressed on the keyboard and basically customize your textbox per keystroke.  I hope this can get you started on the right path.

All else fails, search for key terms you find in code like `e.KeyChar` there is a ton of information out there.

Microsoft usually does a pretty decant job of explaining thing like e.[KeyChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.100).aspx) and e.[Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.100).aspx).

Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah, I find the documentation on the official site to be a complete nightmare. This is probably because the little programming experience I have was in Max/MSP, which is built specifically for musicians, not programmers. Microsoft seems to assume that people coming into Visual Basic are already programmers; not entirely unreasonable, but extremely frustrating for me.